# Can you move "lists" to folders within a library?

Tags: list

I would like to move three lists I created by uploaded excel spreadsheet to folders within a library.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you do want to do that? There must be a better way...

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. The best you can do is enable content types in your document library and add the Link to a Document contenttype. Then create 3 Link to a Document items in the list and point them to the respective lists allitems.aspx page, or whatever view you prefer.

Comment: are you saying that you can't add a "list item" content type to a doc library?

Comment: Unless it's changed in 2013, no you cannot add list content types like Item to a Document library.